# LoadError: no such file to load -- mechanize

Tags: rubygems, mechanize

Any suggestions why this doesn't work?

```
[app (master)]$ gem install mechanize
Successfully installed mechanize-2.5.1
1 gem installed
[app (master)]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.2p318 :001 > require 'mechanize'
LoadError: no such file to load -- mechanize
```

I've tried some other Stack Overflow answers like deleting other versions of ruby but no luck so far.

Running OS X 10.8.2.

EDIT 1

I've just deleted rvm, all versions of Ruby (apart from the system version), and all gems and started all over again. So, I should now have a clean system but I'm getting the same problem.

EDIT 2

New version of Rails is 3.2.3 and get a similar message:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> require 'mechanize'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mechanize
```

Comment: I have the same problem using Rails 3.2.11

Comment: I have the excat same issue as you two. Hopefully someone might be able to help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've got the same problem with a rails 2.2.2 app.

Comment: Please tell us How you solved this. I have same loading problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Do this in same shell you're going to run your command.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi I just tested the solution, but running the command before running rails console, but I also receive the error with "cannot load such file -- mechanize".

Comment: No change. I'm now running Rails 3.2.3 and get a very similar message. Have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Type `which ruby` and change the path at the top of `script/rails` to match the one returned by the previous command.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hack. What happens when you update rails? Does this file get overwritten? Anyway, updated this file but still get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer was more simple, and idiotic. In my gem file, I had uncommeted 'sass-rails' from the assets group. I still don't know why this would fail in production and work in my test enviroment - further more, I didn't use Sass but just regular CSS files...

Comment: sass-rails is still there. For me it looks like this:   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'